# Split a text with a '-' separator

Tags: split, delimiter

I have a textbox, 'txtSearch'. The textbox may contain a value like '100-110'

I want to split the string between the '-' so that I can compare 100 and 110. 
I want to assign 100 to variable 'a' and 110 to variable 'b'

How do i do it?

language is javascript

Comment: I'm going to stab in the dark and guess VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This:

```
var str= document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
var n=str.split("-"); 

var a = n[0];
var b = n[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str= document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
var n=str.split("-");
```

//    The result of n will be an array with the values: you can get it like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    alert(n[i]);
     }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I edited my question. the language is javascript. I want to assign the value before and after the delimiter to variables.

Comment: This works thanks. the problem with this, is I can only assign it to 1 variable everytime it loops. I want the two, to be assigned to 2 different variables

Comment: @aedz : in this n[0] = 100 and n[1] =110 , there is no  need to use for loop  ;; for knowledge i represented it ; if it is solved then consider upvoting and marking the answer as the correct one :)